# Prolog: find and put into the list duplicates

Tags: prolog

Good day, guys. Can't figure out, why prolog predicate is putting all duplicates into my new list. F.e. I have to pick all duplicates:

```
?- duplicates([a, b, a, a, d, d], R). 
R = [a, d]
```

I have wrote this prolog program:

```
duplicates([], []).
duplicates([First|Rest], NewRest) :- 
    not(member(First, Rest)), 
    duplicates(Rest, NewRest).
duplicates([First|Rest], [First|NewRest]) :- 
    member(First, Rest), 
    duplicates(Rest, NewRest).
```

But it returns:

```
R = [a, a] .
```

I think I need to put a (!) sign somewhere, but cannot understand, where. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
duplicates([], []).
duplicates([First|Rest], NewRest) :- 
    \+ member(First, Rest),
    duplicates(Rest, NewRest).
duplicates([First|Rest], NewRest) :- 
    duplicates(Rest, NewRest),
    member(First, NewRest).
duplicates([First|Rest], [First|NewRest]) :- 
    member(First, Rest), 
    duplicates(Rest, NewRest),
    \+ member(First, NewRest).

?- duplicates([a, b, a, a, d, d], R).
R = [a, d] ;
false.
```

I have choosen a version where you don't need cuts (the `!`). Also I added another rule: elements in `NewRest` can appear only once. Note: membership in `NewRest` can be testet only after unification of all of its entries.

Comment: Please use the standard `\+/1` predicate instead of the old and deprecated `not/1` predicate.

Comment: thanks for the hint, I haven't coded in prolog since a decade.

Answer (score 2):

library([aggregate](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)) allows a compact solution for your problem.

```erlang
duplicates(L,D) :- findall(K,(aggregate(count,member(K,L),C),C>1),D).

?- duplicates([a, b, a, a, d, d], R).
R = [a, d].
```

Clearly, it's less immediate to grasp than @Raubsauger' good answer, and not available in every Prolog out there.

Comment: I should not use any libraries of Prolog.

Comment: @wollenS: I agree, library(aggregate) is a beast, but hope you agree that member/2 is a library(lists) member as well, albeit much much easier to craft yourself when compared to aggregate/3. And - en passant - an optimized member/2 predicate is not easy to spot for Prolog newbies...

Comment: To write your own member is very easy, so not a big deal here that guys showed a solution with member.